# Output weighted f1-score for KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm trying to ouput only the weighted f1-score for test data in a KNeighborsClassifier.

**I can do this:**

```
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train) 
result = neigh.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(test_tags, result))
```

**Returning:**

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       1.00      0.40      0.57         5
          2       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
          3       0.20      1.00      0.33         1

avg / total       0.74      0.43      0.46         7
```

**I'm also aware of:**

`sklearn.metrics.f1_score`.

And understand the example on http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html
.

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
```

But how do I apply this to my KNeighborsClassifier code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve with below.

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train) 
result = neigh.predict(X_test)

precision_recall_fscore_support(test_tags, result, average='weighted')[2]
```

Where `test_tags` are true values, and `result` is predicted values.